# "Unable to connect to move_group" when running another machine

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to controll my RobotArm via Rviz, followed a tutorial and everything works fine.

In the end: I ran rviz on an external device with the Rosmaster sitting on the robot itself.

For testing purposes i used the intern Rosmaster and then to try it for "real" i got to connect to the Rosmaster of the Robot "export ROS_MASTER_URI = http: //hostname:11311")".

Everything is the same except that when i run the demo.launch on the "real" Rosmaster i got:

```
[ERROR] [1629309314.819565696]: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (30s)
```

I already checkt the connection: both machines are connected to the internet via eth0. Both can be pinged. They also can ping each other(Hostname and IP works) and both can get access to them via ssh(Hostname and IP works).
The ROS_MASTER_URI is definitive the same.
There is no time difference between the machines (same timezone).
I've also checked the docs wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup and wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines.

That's it. Nothing more shows up or happens and i am not able to find something that helps.
If you do have have any questions about my setup. I'll try to answer asap.

External Device (Virtual Machine):

- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- ROS PARAMETERS

  - /rosdistro: kinetic
  - /rosversion: 1.12.17
  - Network connection: Bridged

Robot (Raspberry Pi 4 B):

- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- ROS PARAMETERS

  - /rosdistro: kinetic
  - /rosversion: 1.12.17

Thanks,
Kiwi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384755/%22unable-to-connect-to-move_group%22-when-running-another-machine/) by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-20**:
Since you don't mention it: you've checked [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)  *and*  [wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)?

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
yeah i've run threw this pages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-20**:
Ok. So that all worked? Without having to set `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME` anywhere? Bi-directional `rostopic echo` etc?

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
I seems that connected finally because when i look at (rostopic echo /rosout)
this comes up(definitive not what the host is showing):
https://pasteboard.co/KgLu8Lo.png (image of /rosout on VM)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-20**:
Right. So:

1. do not post screenshots of terminals. It violates the support guidelines and is also unnecessary: it's all text, so just copy-paste it into your original question text as an update (use the `edit` button/link to edit)
2. please perform the test as described in the multi-machine terminal (using `talker` and `listener`), or run `rostopic echo /chatter` on the first host and `rostopic pub -r1 /chatter std_msgs/String 'ping'` on the second. Then switch the roles (ie: `pub` on the second host, and `echo` on the first)

Don't use random topics, and be very clear about what you're running where.

Additionally: please update your question with the values of `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` for all involved hosts.

---

Edit: I'm getting a feeling I understand why things don't work for you, but you should have run into that when doing the test (which you claim you've done), so I'm going to wait for you to report the result of the test.

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
Ok, no matter which machine I run the pub or echo on, the listener does not receive anything.
Also no error is showing up.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-20**:
I've posted an answer.

You do agree with me that this problem should have shown up if you'd run the tests described on the wiki pages I linked in an earlier comment?

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
Yeah fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the image you shared earlier we see this:

[image: ros_hostname set to localhost]

I expect the fact you set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to `localhost` is the cause of your problems.

`localhost` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`, which is the loopback IP. No host can contact another host on that IP.

If your Pi tries to reach your VM, it will be told it can do that on `localhost`. But the Pi's `localhost` is not the VM's `localhost`. So it tries to connect to itself and that will obviously fail.

I believe the networking and multi-machine tutorials are pretty clear: set that variable only if needed, and if you set it, make sure to set it to a hostname that *all* involved hosts can resolve.

Unfortunately that was ambiguous, as `ping localhost` will obviously work on all hosts. It just won't work when trying to connect to *remote* hosts.

I suggest setting `ROS_HOSTNAME` to the actual hostname of your machines (so not `localhost`) and trying again. If that doesn't work, unset `ROS_HOSTNAME` and set `ROS_IP` to the IP address of the machines.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
It worked, when i unset the HOSTNAME and only used the IP.

Thank you @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-20**:
Please make sure you're not using DHCP.

if you are, your IP may change the next time you boot up your Pi or VM and whatever you've configured `ROS_IP` with could become incorrect. That would again lead to connection problems.

Using DHCP is fine, but then you'd have to make an IP reservation for your two host or use `ROS_HOSTNAME` and make sure your hostnames can be resolved by all involved hosts.

**Comment by [Kiwi_gamer01](https://answers.ros.org/users/71356/kiwi_gamer01/) on 2021-08-20**:
I've already sorted everything out.
Thanks